# fedora 24 run docker 32-bit image

Tags: docker, containers, fedora, lxc-docker

The host is Fedora 24 i686 version, kernel version is `4.6.3-300.fc24.i686`. Also installed docker. When following the [fedora getting started with docker wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Getting_started_with_docker) the `docker run` command failed with errors:

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t fedora /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'fedora:latest' locally
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/fedora ... 
latest: Pulling from docker.io/library/fedora
7c91a140e7a1: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:a97914edb....5b04509bb7d
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/fedora:latest
exec format error
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 88a0....b54d: 
[9] System error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of 
type libcontainer.genericError.
```

I'm guessing this image is a 64-bit image. How to verify this? Where to get a 32-bit fedora docker image?

The docker version is 1.10.3 from fedora 24 repo.

Comment: I found a debian 32-bit image named `32bit/debian`. It's a version 8.5 jessie. A few other 32-bit images are at `https://hub.docker.com/u/32bit/`, with source repo at `https://github.com/docker-32bit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the only current provider of Fedora 32-bit docker images:

https://hub.docker.com/r/nickcis/fedora-32

There is a link to a github page there that contains instructions for how to build your own images for 32-bit Fedora >= 24.

Comment: I can confirm that there are no official Fedora 32-bit x86 Docker images.